# Is there a quick way to get to Winterhold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need to get to the  magic college because I would like to learn magic.

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted.  This was a legitimate question.  :O

Comment: I walked over there, its a nice walk. Beare of the snow wolfs, they are quiet tough at the beginning.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Skyrim.

Answer (score 15):

You can get there by riding a cart! There's a carriage outside of every major city. Pay a small fee and you are there.

Comment: Stop right there, criminal scum! You've violated this cart, pay the driver a fine or serve your sentence!

Comment: I violated the cart? Oh well, i guess i WILL have to pay the fine. This behavior doesn't seem to be appropriate for this site...

Comment: @ChaosPointDK He's joking; fines are used to pay compensation for something you've done wrong.  A better word for your answer may be "fee".

Comment: I rode on a cart once, then I took an arrow to the knee...

Comment: Small fee? I just dare them to chop me head off instead... then i Fus their asses.

Comment: @desaivv I keep trying to decapitate the driver and dragon-shouting at him, but he just looks at me and talks about the weather and doesn't take me to Winterhold. :'(

Comment: @SevenSidedDie have you tried shouting the name of the place you want to go to?

Comment: Fus ro dah the Cart Driver's face? Guys, he faces such winds EVERY, FRIGGIN, DAY! He just shrugs it off now. Not even Dragonborn himself is that badass.